# use serial communication over TCP / UDP

Tags: interface, serial-port

I have several apps which communicate through serial comm (RS-232 and RS-422), and i would like them to communicate through TCP or UDP without changing them. Another point is that some of the apps must run on linux.
I would like to know if there are exsiting tools for that purpose..

Thanks a lot!
Tal

Answer (score 0):

If all you do with your serial port is read and write bytes, and if precise timing is not a concern, then you may be able to replace your serial port object with a TCP socket and send the exact same data over the socket as you would have sent over the port.  The biggest complications are that the timing on a TCP socket is *much* looser than on a serial port, and TCP sockets' mechanisms for sending "out-of-band" data are different from those of a serial port.

I am unaware of any standards for sending serial data via UDP.  Conceptually, it would seem like a useful thing to have since there are many serial-port protocols-based in which it would be more useful to drop data that can't be delivered within a certain time frame than to deliver it late.  For example, if the intended recipient of serial-port data is an embedded controller that will sometimes so busy that it drops some incoming data, but which will respond within a few milliseconds to everything it does receive, a one-second hiccup on a TCP connection [not unusual] may cause software which expects to be talking directly to the controller to retransmit a command a dozen times.  Even if the device would be capable of detecting and rejecting retransmissions it receives, it would be better for the earlier transmission requests to be abandoned than to have them be delivered late.  Note that to be useful, a UDP-based scheme would have to include enough wrapper logic to guarantee that packets would never be delivered out of order; once the data for a packet has been sent to the serial port, any UDP packets which are received later despite having been sent earlier must be discarded; the recipient should probably include logic so that if many out-of-sequence packets are received, it will wait a little while after receiving any packet whose sequence number does not immediately follow the last one, to see if missing packets show up before it commits itself to discarding them.

Comment: @HaiBi Hi, I was looking for something out of the box and without changes in the applications. For example - hardware solution could be [DeviceMaster](http://www.comtrol.com/products/devicemaster-ethernet-device-servers/devicemaster-pro), and a software solution for windows could be [Null-modem emulator (com0com)](http://com0com.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: @Tal: Off-the-shelf solutions modules for TCP/IP if timing is not critical.  Many of them simply bridge the a TCP socket stream to the serial port.  As noted, timing tends to be really sloppy with such things, but if your protocol can tolerate that they may work.

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard tool to do that.  I am thinking to develop one.  UDP is ideal in this case since it is 100% guaranteed that there is no out of order packet delivery on a short LAN as is in your case.

Answer (score 0):

In several projects I have used free tool Hercules (https://www.hw-group.com/software/hercules-setup-utility) for protoyping and testing phases. No advertising intended, just a recommendation.